# Como abrir Pop Up automatico?

Tags: html, css, popup

Tenho o seguinte codigo de modal

```html
<a href="#openModal">Clique</a>
<div id="openModal" class="modalDialog">
      <div>
        <a href="#close" title="Close" class="closeModal">
        <!-- Conteúdo do Modal -->
        <h2>Análise fiscal?</h2>
        <p>O status de "Análise Fiscal" prestado pela transportadora significa que sua encomenda foi retida pela Receita Federal para que os mesmos confiram informações constantes na nota fiscal, e verificarem se os impostos estão sendo pagos corretamente, devido às diferenças tributárias de cada estado.</p>
        <hr>
        <!-- Conteúdo do Modal -->
      </div>
    </div>
 <script type="text/javascript">
    // <![CDATA[
    document.querySelector("#go").addEventListener("submit", function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      window.location.replace('http://status.ondeestameupedido.com/tracking/6560/' + document.getElementById("pedido").value);


    });
    // ]]>
  </script>
<style>
  .pedido {

      margin-top: -300px;
      margin-left: 40%;
      margin-right: 40%;
      margin-bottom: 100px;

  }

  .teste {

  padding-top: 100px;

  }
.modalDialog {
  position: fixed;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  background: rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
  z-index: 99999;
  opacity:0;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 400ms ease-in;
  -moz-transition: opacity 400ms ease-in;
  transition: opacity 400ms ease-in;
  pointer-events: none;
}
.modalDialog:target {
  opacity:1;
  pointer-events: auto;
}
.modalDialog > div {
  width: 400px;
  position: relative;
  margin: 10% auto;
  padding: 5px 20px 13px 20px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  background: #fff;
}
.closeModal {
  background: #606061;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  line-height: 25px;
  position: absolute;
  right: -12px;
  text-align: center;
  top: -10px;
  width: 24px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-weight: bold;
  -webkit-border-radius: 12px;
  -moz-border-radius: 12px;
  border-radius: 12px;
  -moz-box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px #000;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px #000;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px #000;
}
.closeModal:after {
  content: "\d7";
}
.closeModal:hover { 
  background: #f00; 
}

</style>
```

Quando eu clico na palavra "Clique" ele abre. Como eu deveria fazer para ele abrir automaticamente quando abrir a página, sem precisa clicar em algo?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Vc pode só inverter a lógica. Deixa ele iniciar com `opacity:1`, e quando vc clicar no botão `X` para fechar vc usa o `:target` para colocar `opacity:0`

```css
.pedido {
    margin-top: -300px;
    margin-left: 40%;
    margin-right: 40%;
    margin-bottom: 100px;
}

.teste {
    padding-top: 100px;
}

.modalDialog {
    position: fixed;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
    z-index: 99999;
    opacity:1;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 400ms ease-in;
    -moz-transition: opacity 400ms ease-in;
    transition: opacity 400ms ease-in;
    /* pointer-events: none; */
}

.modalDialog:target {
    opacity: 0;
    pointer-events: auto;
}

.modalDialog>div {
    width: 400px;
    position: relative;
    margin: 10% auto;
    padding: 5px 20px 13px 20px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    background: #fff;
}

.closeModal {
    background: #606061;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    line-height: 25px;
    position: absolute;
    right: -12px;
    text-align: center;
    top: -10px;
    width: 24px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-weight: bold;
    -webkit-border-radius: 12px;
    -moz-border-radius: 12px;
    border-radius: 12px;
    -moz-box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px #000;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px #000;
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px #000;
}

.closeModal:after {
    content: "\d7";
}

.closeModal:hover {
    background: #f00;
}
```

```html
<div id="openModal" class="modalDialog">
    <div>
        <a href="#openModal" title="Close" class="closeModal"></a>
            <!-- Conteúdo do Modal -->
            <h2>Análise fiscal?</h2>
            <p>O status de "Análise Fiscal" prestado pela transportadora significa que sua encomenda foi retida
                pela Receita Federal para que os mesmos confiram informações constantes na nota fiscal, e
                verificarem se os impostos estão sendo pagos corretamente, devido às diferenças tributárias de cada
                estado.</p>
            <hr>
            <!-- Conteúdo do Modal -->
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Funcionou, mas ao fechar não consigo clicar em nenhum local na pagina. Saberia dizer o que pode estar ocasionando isso? Utilizo a plataforma magento, estou colocando como bloco estatico e escolhendo a pagina a ser mostrada com widget.

Comment: @JVEUZEBIO eu imaginei que isso poderia acontecer!!, isso acontece pq nesse seu código vc não esta "removendo" o popup da tela, vc está apenas tirando a opacidade,. Ele fica transparente, mas na verdade continua ali por cima de tudo :/.. Esse modelo de popup é meio complicado para usar mesmo. Vou pensar em algo que te ajude com essa opção, ou então vc vai ter que usar outro modelo... me da uns min

Comment: Ah entendi, se você tiver alguma ideia de outro modelo me ajudaria muito

Comment: @JVEUZEBIO cara não vai ficar tão bonitinho com esse efeito de transição, mas se vc trocar onde está opacity:0, por display:none, e onde está opacity:1 por display:block, vc consegue o que uer. usando o display:none vc vai remover o elemento da tela, e consegue clicar no que estiver na tela, só que ele vai sumir de uma vez, e não com essa transição....

Comment: Ah legal, sim ficou mais direto. Mas resolveu meu problema, obrigado!

Comment: Sabe alguma maneira de esconder o #openModal da url?]

Comment: @JVEUZEBIO só da para limpar usando JS ou jQuery, e eu não manjo nada de JS. O problema é que esse modelo de popup usar o :target para setar o CSS no popup, então é por isso que ele "suja" a url. Acho que já vi coisa aqui no site sobre isso, vc vai ter que pesquisar...

Comment: Ah certo, vou dar uma pesquisada obrigado